# pitfalls for multiplayer realtime game with nodeJs and Android Java

Tags: node.js, websocket, multiplayer

I'm developing my first multiplayer real-time game with node.js websockets as back-end and Java Android as client.

Are there any common pitfalls that I should avoid?

(I already read all the suggested SO questions about it but the most recent one was for 2021)

I mean something structural, code structure choices, and so on, not opinion based answers please.

Now I'm using the `ws` and `express` libraries for node.js and on my VPS (under Linux with apache2 and ufw) I have the SSL active, generated with certbot.

I'll publish the game only on Play Store.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

const players = new Map();

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(msg);
    
    if(data.type === 'joined') {
      players.set(ws, { x: 0, y: 0, score: 0 });
    }
    else if (data.type === 'update') {
      // TODO: check here the genuinity of the arrived data?
      
      let playerData = players.get(ws);
      if (playerData) {
        playerData.x = data.x;
        playerData.y = data.y;
        ...
      }
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    players.delete(ws);
  });
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server started');
});
```